# Which event is being triggered from a menu paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box that users can type in. When the user keys up, the search is performed. There are checks to see the length of text in the search box.

```
    // THE SEARCH STRING IS BEING POPULATED
    $SEARCH.SearchString.keyup($SEARCH.utilities.doSearch);
```

When someone uses ctrl+v to paste text, this works perfect. When someone uses the menu to paste, like in the image below, the search is not performed.

I am not sure of what to call this menu so it's difficult to search for an answer. What event should I have JavaScript listen for when this menu is present and the user selects "Paste"?

[image]

Comment: can use `paste` or `input` events http://jsfiddle.net/jeuj3ozz/ Would double check for cross browser support though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` event triggers for both paste and typing, thus could be used in lieu of keyup or keydown and cover both scenarios for user entry in modern browsers.

The caveat is that IE shows support starting in IE9 as well as  IE9 has some different behavior issues .

> IE 9 does not fire an input event when the user removes characters
>   from input filled by keyboard, cut, or drag operations.

```
$('input').on('input', function(e){
    $('body').append('<br>Input event triggered, value = ' + this.value);   
});
```

Reference: **[MDN input event docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)**

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeuj3ozz/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: This worked perfectly. I will have to write in some exceptions for IE as you suggest.

Comment: Might consider creating some sort of event support tester or something. This actually was good for me to get back on top of also since I've ignored some html5 issues like this for a while due to having to support older browsers. Those browsers are fading away now

Answer (score 1):

There is `onpaste` but it doesn't seem to be part of any standard so your milage may vary

```
$(selector).on('paste', function() {
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: also, Firefox doesn't seem to update immediately. See https://web.archive.org/web/20140110200733/http://css.dzone.com/articles/paste-wasteland-or-why-onpaste (site is down currently)